# GTK settings file for RCP application

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

We can change the look, style and behaviours of `gnome` by changing the setting in **~/.gtkrc-2.0** file. And it apply to all applications.

In my RCP application menu's are not showing icons as the option `menus-have-icons` was not enabled in GTK settings by default. When I enabled this then menus shows icons.

So on **Linux Mint**  my RCP application shows icons in menu as this option was enabled by default, but on **Ubuntu 13.10** it doesn't as this option was NOT enabled by default.

How I can make my application looks same on Linux Mint and Ubuntu 13.10?
i.e How I can override GTK settings in my RCP application.

Can I create a GTK settings file for my application only?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. Your RCP application should respect the user settings, otherwise it is a bad application. If an Ubuntu user wants to see menu icons, he will have set that option by himself. If the option is not set on the other hand, *all* applications should show no menu icons, yours included.

The underlying graphical framework of RCP applications (SWT) was actually invented to make RCP applications look as native as possible (and therefore different on different operating systems), and not as similar as possible on all platforms.

Comment: 100% Agreed.But is there any to do it.